# the code does not work as intended (c, checking a pixel if it has changed and clicking on somewhere else)

Tags: c, runtime-error

it needs to check the x 1500 y 100th pixel and click the mouse twice when it detects a change for 200 times, but it doesnt do anything and randomly closes itself. im a beginner and i have no idea why it doesnt work, would love it if someone helps fixing it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++){
        int x=1500, y=100;
        HWND dtp = GetDesktopWindow();
        HDC s = GetDC(dtp);
        int w = GetDeviceCaps(s, 590);
        int h = GetDeviceCaps(s, 880);
    
        DWORD z = GetPixel(s,x,y);
    
        do {
            sleep(0.10);
        } while (GetPixel(s, x, y) == z);
    
        sleep(5);
    
        INPUT m[] = {
            {x*65535/w, y*65535/h, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE},
            {0, 0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN},
            {0, 0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP},
        };
    
        SendInput(sizeof(m)/sizeof(*m), m, sizeof(*m));
        
        sleep(1);
        
        INPUT b[] = {
            {0, 0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN},
            {0, 0, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP},
        };
    
        SendInput(sizeof(b)/sizeof(*b), m, sizeof(*b));
        
        sleep(3);

        ReleaseDC(dtp,s);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`? Is this actually C++ code? Also it's unusual to see both `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`. The description isn't very revealing: "it doesnt do anything and randomly closes itself". What *does* it do - exactly?

Comment: its supposed to be a c code, i probably misremembered the library. the sleep function didnt work before i added unistd.h, and the code does literally nothing when you run it. i dont think so

Comment: "It doesn't do anything". You have a loop of 200 which sleeps for at least 10 seconds each time. 2000 seconds is ... over half an hour. Not only that but each loop will wait for you to press a key.

Comment: Note that `sleep(0.10)` is incorrect. The function takes integer seconds.

Comment: I recommend that you use the function [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) instead of `sleep`. That function allows you to specify milliseconds instead of seconds. Also, it does not seem appropriate to mix POSIX functions with Windows API functions, unless you have a specific reason to do so.